# TextView is not updated with the new date selected by the datepicker

Tags: android, textview, android-logcat, android-datepicker

I have Set Two Date Pickers(Namely Check In and Check Out). For the first time when I run the app everything is fine,the date which I clicked is displayed in the TextView.But without running the app second time When I try to click the Check In button the date  is not changing in the TextView. But the date is changing in the LogCat. At the same time the Check Out button is working fine for the first time and also with second time(without running the app again).  Kindly solve my issue.

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button checkIn, checkOut, checkavailability;
TextView displayCheckIn, displayCheckOut;
int year, month, day;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID2 = 2;
int cur = 0;
String chidate, chodate;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkInBtn);
    checkOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkOutBtn);
    displayCheckIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayCheckIntv);
    displayCheckOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayCheckOuttv);
    checkavailability = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkAvailabilityBtn);
    setCurrentDateOnView();//declaring a method to display the current date in the opening
    addListenerOnButton();
}

//settin the current date in the opening page
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //displaying current date in the check in textView
    displayCheckIn.setText(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day);
    //displaying the current date in check out textView by getting the text from the check in view
    displayCheckOut.setText(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day);
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    checkIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
    checkOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID2);
        }
    });
    checkavailability.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //checkAvailability();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            System.out.println("onCreate Dialog  :" + id);
            cur = DATE_DIALOG_ID;
            //Displaying the Date Picker Dialog on the screen with today's date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);


        case DATE_DIALOG_ID2:
            System.out.println("onCreateDialog   :" + id);
            cur = DATE_DIALOG_ID2;
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);

    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int syear, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        year = syear;
        month = monthOfYear;
        day = dayOfMonth;
        if (cur == DATE_DIALOG_ID) {
            displayCheckIn.setText(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day);
            chidate = displayCheckIn.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(chidate);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),chidate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            displayCheckOut.setText(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day);
            chodate = displayCheckOut.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(chodate);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),chodate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
};
```

//This is the code which I want to check the Checkin date every time.

```
/*public void checkAvailability() {
    String[] datesin = {"2014-12-16", "2014-12-17", "2014-12-18"};
    for (int j = 0; j < datesin.length; j++) {
        if (datesin[j].equals(chidate)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Room Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Room Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}*/
```

}

And My XML is :

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/displayCheckIntv"
    android:text="Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckIn"
    android:id="@+id/checkInBtn"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check Out"
    android:id="@+id/checkOutBtn"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkInBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check Out"
    android:id="@+id/displayCheckOuttv"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkOutBtn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkOutBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check Availability"
    android:id="@+id/checkAvailabilityBtn"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/displayCheckOuttv"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/displayCheckOuttv" />

</RelativeLayout>
```